# Can a span of an orthonormal subset be embedded into $l^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, hilbert-spaces

Rudin - RCA p.85

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\beta$ be an orthonormal subset of $H$.

Let $T:H\rightarrow l^2(\beta)$ be the continuous linear transformation such that $T(x)(v)=(x , v)$ for $x\in H, v\in \beta$.

Rudin, in his text, simply wrote that $T(span(\beta))$ dense subset of $l^2(\beta)$. However, I think $T$ is injective on $span(\beta)$. Is this true?

Define $\mathscr{A}=\{\sum f(i)\chi_{\{i\}}: f\in \mathbb{C}^\beta, supp(f) \text{ is finite } \}$

It can be directly checked that $T(span(\beta))=\mathscr{A}$ and $T$ is injective on $span(\beta)$. Also note that $\mathscr{A}$ is dense in $l^2(\beta)$. Moreover, since $||Tx||_2= ||x||$ on $\overline{span(\beta)}$, $T$ is injective on $\overline{span(\beta)}$ and $T(\overline{span(\beta)})=l^2(\beta)$. This shows that $\overline{span(\beta)}$ and $l^2(\beta)$ are isometrically isomorphic. Is it really true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you have to verify this. Suppose $x=\sum f(v)v\in\operatorname{span}\beta$, where $v\in\beta$ and the sum is finite. Show that $\Vert Tx\Vert^2=\Vert x\Vert^2= \sum|f(v)|^2$ (use orthonormality of $\beta$). Thus, if $Tx=0$, we must have $x=0$, which means that $T$ is injective.